# Angularjs url param retrieving

Tags: angularjs

Here I have link on my local host.

```
http://localhost/anguarjs/ng-view.html#/7
```

The last digit in URL is ID value. How I can retrieve it with angularjs. There is a way with $routeProvide. but this requires to load a partial file. I want something simple without loading partial file.

Thanks is advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you change  your url to: 
localhost/anguarjs/ng-view.html#/?idValue=7

And in your javascript:

```
var id = ($location.search()).idValue;
```

More information about $location: [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24location)

Answer (score 0):

Use `$routeParams` for accessing it. Inject `$routeParams` into your controller and access it via `$routeParams.paramName` where `paramName` is the name you are using for your param.